# Splinter: selecting the correct button

Tags: python, splinter

I am trying to automate logging into a website so I can retrieve information from my weather station.  The login page is at http://www.lacrossealertsmobile.com/v1.2/#userLogin

When I look at the source code I see several lines that say

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

I want to select the button for the login page being displayed when I visit the page above. The section of code with the login is

```
<div data-role="page" id="userLogin">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-container">
        <div class="logo-banner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row list-group-item active">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h4 class="text-center" style="font-weight: 500; margin:5px;">User Login</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="font-size:1.2em;">
                <form role="form" id="formLogin" style="margin: 10px 0;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">User Name (email address)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iLogEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="iLogPass" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-warning" id="userLogin-warning" style="display:none;">warning text</div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <br>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="row list-group-item list-group-item-success" id="newUserDiv">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h4 class="text-center" style="font-weight: 300; margin:5px;">New Users - Click here to get started</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Splinter documentation says

> Finding methods are chainable, so you can find the descendants of a previously found element.

So I tried to do this with the following:

```
login = browser.find_by_id('userLogin')
login.first.find_by_text('Submit')
```

I am trying to do this in order to find the "Submit" within the login section, and then I expected I could modify the code to be

```
login.first.find_by_text('Submit')[0].click()
```

This did not work.  I eventually found out that it is because element [0] above is not visible.  By trial and error I found that the visible button, the one I want, is element [5].  In fact it looks like my chained search did not do what I thought.  The 2 searches below return different addresses for the objects found, but in either case it is element [5] that maps to the Submit button on the displayed form

```
>>> login.first.find_by_text('Submit')
[<splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x03320FF0>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x033AD170>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x033AD1B0>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x033AD210>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x033AD250>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x033AD290>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x033AD2D0>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x033AD310>]
>>> browser.find_by_text('Submit')
[<splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x0326CEB0>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x0326C590>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x033200F0>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x033209B0>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x033201B0>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x03320190>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x033207D0>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x033AD350>]
```

So my question is why didn't the chained search return the descendant of the  "userLogin", which is the Submit button I want?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is probably because it is not a direct descendant of the object you will find using that ID.

Alternatively, you could locate by Xpath using the Absolute Xpath or try using the object directly above it in the DOM.